# Update VSTS test case status to PASS / FAIL using rest api

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I want to update a test cases status in VSTS using rest api.

Based on test case Id I want update the testcase to PASS or FAIL.

Which rest api can be used from where I can pass status?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can update `the last test result` for a sepcific test case, then the `outcome` will reflect on the test case.

1. Get the last test run ID first. (User the REST API - [Get a list of
   test runs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/integrate/previous-apis/test/runs?view=tfs-2018#get-a-list-of-test-runs))
2. Use the REST API to update the specific test result.

   ```
   PATCH https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/test/Runs/{runId}/results?api-version=5.0-preview.5
   ```

   Request Body

   ```
   [
     {  
       "id": 100000,
       "state": "Completed",
       "outcome": "Passed"
     }
   ]
   ```

Please see [Update test results for a test run](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/vsts/test/results/update?view=vsts-rest-5.0) for details.

You can reference this similar thread : [Changing the outcome field of testcases within a test suite in Tfs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52187456/changing-the-outcome-field-of-testcases-within-a-test-suite-in-tfs/52202550#52202550)

---

**UPDATE:**

If you just want to mark a test case to `Passed` or `Failed` and generate a RUNID, then you can use below REST API: (Provide the PlanID, suite ID and test point ID in the request body)

```
POST http://SERVER:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/{ProjectName or ID}/_api/_testManagement/BulkMarkTestPoints

Content-Type : application/json

Request Body:

{"planId":36,"suiteId":38,"testPointIds":[5],"outcome":3}
```

1. You can get the `Plan Id`, `Suite Id` from web portal (R*eference
   below screenshot*)
2. You can use below REST API to get the `testPointIds`:

   ```
   GET http://SERVER:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/{ProjectName or ID}/_apis/test/Plans/36/Suites/38/points
   ```
3. For `outcome`:  `2` means `Passed`, `3` means `Failed`

[image]

Comment: thank you Andy. In get last test run, where can i find the details of Owner & build uri?

Comment: I want to update the testcase based on test caseID and generate RunID. Using RUNID I will invoke restapi call to attach my result files.

Comment: thank you Andy. The approach provided by you worked. But I used vsts api's with same approach. :)

Comment: @Andy...Is it possible I can get PlanId & SuiteId by just passing TestcaseId/WorkItemId to a restapi? Actually I have testcaseId which is a workItem, I want to get in which testplan and test suite the testcaseid resides.

Comment: @Amruta Yes, you can use the API to achieve that, suggest you opening a new thread for this question, then I can post the answer for you.

Comment: How can I update the outcome status for same RunId? If the outcome status is passed first and afterwards based on some condition in program, the status to be updated will be failed. How can I pass the same in request body? Same RunId and just the status to be updated