# getting unauthorised issue when tried to update the test case status on VSTS through API

Tags: api, azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

We have replicated the same steps mentioned here below.
[Update VSTS test case status to PASS / FAIL using rest api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52331295/update-vsts-test-case-status-to-pass-fail-using-rest-api?noredirect=1&lq=1)

But, we are getting either 401 or 404 or 203 response codes. Could you please help us on the same?

1. Approach with VSTS Webtest

   https://{Organisation Code}.visualstudio.com/{Project Code}/_api/_testManagement/BulkMarkTestPoints?api-version=5.1-preview.1

PayLoad:

```
{
 planId: 187830,
 suiteId: 187831,
 testPointIds: [88212],
 outcome: 2
 }

Headers:
Referer=https://{Organisation Code}.visualstudio.com/{ProjectName}/_testManagement
accept=application/json
accept-language=en-US
Authorization=Basic {PAT}
Host={Organisation Code}.visualstudio.com
content-type=application/json
```

Response:

```
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Pragma : no-cache
Content-Length : 307
Content-Type : application/json; charset=utf-8
Expires : -1
```

APPROACH 2: Using POSTMAN

```
https://{Organisation Code}.visualstudio.com/{Project Code}/_api/_testManagement/BulkMarkTestPoints?api-version=5.1-preview.1
```

PayLoad:

```
{
 planId: 187830,
 suiteId: 187831,
 testPointIds: [88212],
 outcome: 2
 }

Headers:
Referer=https://{Organisation Code}.visualstudio.com/{ProjectName}/_testManagement
accept=application/json
accept-language=en-US
Authorization=Basic {PAT}
Host={Organisation Code}.visualstudio.com
content-type=application/json
```

Note: We have given our credentials as basic auth and facing the same error.

```
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Pragma : no-cache
Content-Length : 307
Content-Type : application/json; charset=utf-8
Expires : -1
```

Comment: did you tried below solution. How did it go?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the steps you mentioned in above thread didnot include authentication. You can refer to below complete sample in powershell scripts.

```
$url = "xxxxxxxxxxxx" # Request url
$connectionToken="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" # personal access token

$base64AuthInfo=  [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($connectionToken)"))

$pipeline = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Headers @{authorization = "Basic $base64AuthInfo"} -Method Get
```

To get your personal access token, you can check steps [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/use-personal-access-tokens-to-authenticate?view=azure-devops).

Comment: Thanks, Levi I will try this and get back with the result. :)