# Update TFS test case status to PASS / FAIL using rest api with python

Tags: python, rest, tfs, python-3.8

I am following the attached instructions from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52331295/update-vsts-test-case-status-to-pass-fail-using-rest-api).

I get the following error:

```
The required anti-forgery form field &quot;__RequestVerificationToken&quot; is not present
```

A have already added cookies `__RequestVerificationToken_L3Rmcw2` as it was required before. How can I solve this problem?

Here is my script:

```
cookies = {
    '__RequestVerificationToken': 'XXXXXXXXXX',
    '__RequestVerificationToken_L3Rmcw2': 'XXXXXXXXXXXX '
}
json_content = 'Content-Type:application/json'
data = 'Request Body:{"planId":XXXXX, "suiteId":XXXXX, "testPointIds":[XXXXX], "outcome":3}'

tfs_update1 = requests.post('https://server:port/tfs/DefaultCollection/Project/_api/_testManagement/BulkMarkTestPoints',
        auth=HttpNtlmAuth(username, password), json=json_content, data=data, cookies=cookies)
print(tfs_update1.content)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Azure DevOps Python API](https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-devops-python-api) to establish a connection using a personal access token and the URL to your Azure DevOps organization. Then get a client from the connection and make API calls.

```
from azure.devops.connection import Connection
from msrest.authentication import BasicAuthentication
import pprint

# Fill in with your personal access token and org URL
personal_access_token = 'YOURPAT'
organization_url = 'https://dev.azure.com/YOURORG'

# Create a connection to the org
credentials = BasicAuthentication('', personal_access_token)
connection = Connection(base_url=organization_url, creds=credentials)
```