# Does Azure provide Rest APIs for posting test automation results to Azure Devops Testlabs?

Tags: azure-devops, automated-tests, azure-rest-api

We are using AZURE test management for creating TestSuites and test plans.
We have selenium automation for all the test suites present in Azure.

Once automation tests are run, we need to post automation results to corresponding test cases in Azure Test suites.
Are there any REST APIs provided by Azure to achieve this?

Thanks in advance
Rajesh

Comment: How about this issue? Have you resolved this issue?

Answer (score 0):

> Does Azure provide Rest APIs for posting test automation results to Azure Devops Testlabs?

The answer is yes.

You could use the REST API [Results - Add](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/test/results/add?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0) to test results to a test run:

```
POST https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/test/Runs/{runId}/results?api-version=6.0
```

Request body:

```
[
  {
    "testCaseTitle": "VerifyWebsiteTheme",
    "automatedTestName": "FabrikamFiber.WebSite.TestClass.VerifyWebsiteTheme",
    "priority": 1,
    "outcome": "Passed"
  },
  {
    "testCaseTitle": "VerifyWebsiteLinks",
    "automatedTestName": "FabrikamFiber.WebSite.TestClass.VerifyWebsiteLinks",
    "priority": 2,
    "outcome": "Failed",
    "associatedBugs": [
      {
        "id": 30
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

You could check [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52331295/update-vsts-test-case-status-to-pass-fail-using-rest-api) and [this thread](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/602005/rest-api-to-post-steps-and-steps-result-of-test-ca.html) for some more details.