# How to update automation test execution results into the test cases in AzureDevOps/TFS

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, azure-devops, automation, continuous-integration

I'm executing test cases in Visual Studio 2019 and after the execution the passed/failed status needs to be updated to the corresponding test case in AzureDevOps/TFS.

I have used to Azure DevOps API to update the results to TFS but there is more easy and straight forward way to accomplish it. Any help would be appreciated. ?

Thanks

Comment: Have you checked my reply? Is it helpful?

Comment: Yes, I checked. This was not I was looking for, but I found the solution in another thread,
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52331295/update-vsts-test-case-status-to-pass-fail-using-rest-api

Comment: Sure. I'm still researching that. Once it is done I will share all the details here itself

Answer (score 0):

You could run automated tests from test plans directly in **Azure test plans**, instead of running from Visual Studio 2019:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/test/run-automated-tests-from-test-hub?view=azure-devops

And you could mark the outcome of the test cases as the screenshot below shows:

[image]