# How to Updating test results in TFS for a specific test case in test suite. All Test Cases should not be marked as In Progress in a Suite in C#

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, tfs, automation, tfs-sdk

I made approach to udpdate tescase result in tfs using API after execution of test case , but it makes all other test case status as inprogress in test suite.

It update the outcome of the test case in the test suite , but it also make rest of the test case as in progress which located in the test suite.

```
ITestCaseResult result = run.QueryResults().FirstOrDefault(r => r.TestCaseId == testCase.Id);
if (result != null)
{

    testRun.Title = testCase.Title;
    result.ComputerName = Environment.MachineName;
    result.Outcome = TestOutcome.Passed;
    result.Comment = comments;
    result.RunBy = testRun.Owner;
    result.State = TestResultState.Completed;
    result.Save();
}
```

I expect,result update should be made on the particular test case id which i am passing at run time and remaining test case status should not change  in the test suite.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without complete code, not sure which part is the root cause, but it maybe related to `if (result != null)`, conditional statements effect the result.

Please try to use below code sample to handle this.

```
publicstaticvoidUpdateResult()
        {

            TfsTeamProjectCollectiontfs = newTfsTeamProjectCollection(TfsTeamProjectCollection.GetFullyQualifiedUriForName(server));
            ITestManagementServicetms = tfs.GetService<ITestManagementService>();
            ITestManagementTeamProjectproj = tms.GetTeamProject(project);
            ITestPlanPlan = proj.TestPlans.Find(1);
IStaticTestSuitesuite = Plan.RootSuite.SubSuites.Where(s => s.Id == 1339).First() asIStaticTestSuite;
            ITestCasetestcase = null;
            testcase = suite.Entries.Where(e => e.Title == "login").First().TestCase;
            ITestRuntestRun = project.TestRuns.Create();
            testRun = Plan.CreateTestRun(false); 

            ITestPointCollectionpoints = Plan.QueryTestPoints("SELECT * FROM TestPoint WHERE TestCaseId ="+ testcase.Id);
            foreach(ITestPointp inpoints)
            {

                testRun.AddTestPoint(p, Plan.Owner);// null);
                //testRun.AddTestPoint(p, null);

            }
            testRun.State = TestRunState.Completed;
            testRun.Save();

            ITestCaseResultCollectionresults = testRun.QueryResults();
            ITestIterationResultiterationResult;
            foreach(ITestCaseResultresult inresults)
            {
                iterationResult = result.CreateIteration(1);
                foreach(ITestSteptestStep inresult.GetTestCase().Actions)
                {
                    ITestStepResultstepResult = iterationResult.CreateStepResult(testStep.Id);
                    stepResult.Outcome = TestOutcome.Passed;                        
                    iterationResult.Actions.Add(stepResult);

                }
                iterationResult.Outcome = TestOutcome.Passed;
                result.Iterations.Add(iterationResult);
                result.Outcome = TestOutcome.Passed;
                result.State = TestResultState.Completed;
                result.Save(true);

            }
            testRun.Save();
            testRun.Refresh();

        }
```

More details take a look at this similar question here: [Changing the outcome field of testcases within a test suite in Tfs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52187456/changing-the-outcome-field-of-testcases-within-a-test-suite-in-tfs)